# Python - How to count occurrences of a number inside of an object?

Tags: python

I need to count the number of occurrences of a number in a object. Not sure how to do it.

I can access to the values in this way:

```
>>> formset_sample.forms[0]._raw_value('type')
>>> '1'
>>> formset_sample.forms[1]._raw_value('type')
>>> '2'
>>> formset_sample.forms[2]._raw_value('type')
>>> '2'
```

This object has len() = 3:

```
>>> len(formset_sample.forms)
>>> 3
```

How can I obtain the occurrences of the number 2? The number '2' have exactly two occurences in this case.

Some clues?

Best Regards,

Comment: There is no number 2. There is a string '2' (which contains a digit).

Comment: note: in general leading `_` implies that the attribute is private and it shouldn't used outside the object class (or its subclasses).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you a list of numbers and count the number of 2s:

```
l = [ f._raw_value('type') for f in formset_sample.forms ]
l.count('2') # I am assuming 2 is a string, or
l.count(2)   # if the number is stored as an integer
```

Now you can use `l` to sort, slice etc.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear to me what you want to achieve. But maybe the `map` function helps you:

```
 values = map(lambda x: x._raw_value('type'), formset_sample.forms)
 # alternate Syntax:
 values = [form._raw_value('type') for form in formset_sample.forms]
 print values
```

should give you the array

```
 ['1', '2', '2']
```

which you could feed into a `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
print Counter(values)
```

should be something like

```
{ '1': 1, '2': 2 }
```

So if you want to put it all in one line:

```
Counter([form._raw_value('type') for form in formset_sample.forms])["2"]
```

Comment: `Counter(form._raw_value('type') for form in formset_sample.forms)['2']` should work too.

Answer (score 2):

this will produce a dictionary with the different types as keys and number of occurences as values:

```
import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
for rv in formset_sample.forms:
  d[rv._raw_value_('type')] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {1:1, 2:1, 3:2}
print a.values().count(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count = sum(f._raw_value('type') == '2' for f in formset_sample.forms)
```